# URL matching with web.py

Tags: python, apache, url, web-applications, web.py

I'm writing a simple "Hello world" with apache and web.py.  The app works when I go to

```
http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp/
```

but not when I go to:

```
http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp
```

My intuition (clearly wrong) was that the following code would have matched either of these addresses.

```
import sys, os
abspath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(abspath)
os.chdir(abspath)

import web

urls = (
      '/.*', 'hello',
      )

class hello:
      def GET(self):
          return "Hello, web.py world."

application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
```

What do I need to change in order to match both of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the URL is "http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp", web.py sees it as "", not as "/". So changing the url pattern to ".*" will work.

But, probably you should fix that in your apache configuration and not in webapp. Add a rule to redirect /webapp to /webapp/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have the **front page** be handled by the class **hello**, all you need is this:

```
urls = (
  '/', 'hello',
  )
```

Or did I misunderstand your intentions?

Answer (score 0):

@Anand Chitipothu is right.

```
http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp/ matches '/'
```

and

```
http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp matches '' #empty string
```

so if you want to fix it in webpy, you can write:

```
urls = (
    '.*', 'hello'    #match all path including empty string
    )
```

or add a Redirect class

```
urls = (
    '/.*', 'hello',  
    '', 'Redirect'
    )
class Redirect(object):
    def GET(self):
        raise web.seeother('/')    # this will make the browser jump to url: http://sandbox-dev.com/webapp/
```